# How do you write a dart only plugin for macos? (Flutter)

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I want to write a flutter plugin that uses different dependencies depending on your platform. The new plugin should provide those with a common abstraction layer.

To achieve this, I need a pure dart package/plugin (not sure what's the right terminology for that case).

I tried to use the federated plugin "pattern" but when setting `flutter.plugin.platforms.macos.dartPluginClass` in my MacOS platform package, flutter tells me it can't find a podspec file although I want to use pure dart.

Is a pure dart plugin for MacOS even possible?

Comment: A pure Dart 'library' is called a `package`. See: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages

Comment: But typically a package has the same code for each platform, I want different code for each platform including different dependencies. Do you know if this is possible using just the package functionality? (without the plugin section in pubspec.yaml)

Comment: Can you give an example of how/why you would want the Dart code to vary? One of the few examples I can think of is `package:path` which has to cope with Windows vs Posix style separators, etc. The solution there is to choose a sensible default based on the platform and allow it to be overridden in the constructor like `var context = p.Context(style: Style.windows);`

Comment: I am currently trying to combine dart_vlc and video_player in a wrapper package/plugin to support video playback on all platforms.

I think I found a solution now using [a podspec like this](https://github.com/invertase/flutterfire_desktop/blob/3ceb217716607fb2b62e16b32b7d79de200453b5/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core_desktop/macos/firebase_core_desktop.podspec).

Comment: Additionally dart_vlc 0.1.8 has a 'feature' that prevents building an macos application using it. Master seems to work.